# for loop into a bunch of files, extract some data of each one and dumb all data into a single file

Tags: bash, file, loops, for-loop, output

i am executing a command over a bunch of files, and extracting a simple data (a number) from each file. 
then i want to dump all this set of data into a txt file, this is my script

```
! /bin/sh

for i in RECO/*.root

do

edmEventSize -v "$i" |grep "File"| cut -d " " -f 4 >  salida2.txt

done
```

but the file salida2.txt just shows the data of the last file, and i need the data of the other files into the same salida2.txt (for example file1 gives me number 1, file2->2, file3->3, etc and in salida2.txt i need all this numbers 1,2,3)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just replace `>` with `>>`. This way you will be appending data, instead of truncating every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `>>` instead of just `>`.  `>>` appends to the redirected file.  `>` simply overwrites it.

[IO Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Comment: done, i was looking for how to close the question, thanks again

Comment: An alternative would be to move the `> salida2.txt` to after the `done` instead of it's current location. That would also be slightly more efficient (avoids repeated open/close cycles on the file), but probably not enough to be noticeable...